# weka say that my data set train and test set are not compatible

Tags: data-mining, weka, prediction, forecasting

[why weka say my train and test file is not compatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXFwT.png)

I'm trying to test my model with new dataset in weka. I have done the same preprocessing step as i have done for building my model. I have all the attributes(train vs test dataset) in same order, same attribute names and data types. But still i'm not able to resolve the issue. Both of the files train and test seems to be similar but the weka explorer is giving me error saying Train and test set are not compatible. How to resolve this error?

Comment: What preprocessing steps are you applying?

Comment: Weka requires the dataset structure to be **exactly** the same: same number of attributes, same attribute names, same values and order for nominal attributes. You can use a diffing tool like [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) to compare the header sections of your files.